# How to Seperate Wordpress Beaver Builder Navigation Menu items into 2nd row

Tags: wordpress, navigation

Within Wordpress Beaver builder plugin I have a menu with:

- 4 menu items that are customized to display as buttons with css class
  in  appearance>customize>additional CSS (these buttons are events
  that will be removed/added based on event times)
- 6 menu items that are the main navigation

All items are in the same menu structure and collapse into a hamburger icon and have a custom breaking point.

Currently both the 4 button menu items and the 6 menu items sit on the same line with half of the 6 menu items falling into a second line.

Is it possible to set all 6 menu items in a row below the 4 buttons and triggering the hamburger icon when they fall into a 3rd line?
[example of what I'm trying to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBkov.png)